# Update WSO2 cache for getting data modified

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

How to update cache record in wso2 and where there cache records gets stored in wso2 api manager. How can I use my own database for inserting cache values.

Answer (score 0):

All of the WSO2 products use [Hazelcast](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.0/manual/html/ch02.html#Map) based caching. Cache isn't maintained in database.

You can find more information about API Manager caching [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Configuring+Caching)

Comment: but can we update that data since there can be a scenario where the backend data gets updated but cache didn't expire

Comment: Only thing you can do is restart the servers to clear up the caches. Otherwise you have to wait for 15mins to clear up the caches and get the updated records.